# .htaccess not working while accessed via SSL/HTTPS in Apache2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have a problem with .htaccess configuration. My webserver is Apache2, and my website was coded by PHP. But, I have some trouble with .htaccess.

While I'm accessing it via non-ssl (http://mywebsite.dev), my .htaccess was work. I use .htaccess for URL Rewrite and handling error by custom template. But, when I access it via SSL (https://mywebsite.dev), for Index page was work. But, when I access https://mywebsite.dev/page/about, it's display 404 Not Found (displaying default 404 Not Found page, not my custom page. It's mean, my .htaccess code not load).

For my URL structure, it was http://mywebsite.dev/?load=page&page=about. If I access http://mywebsite.dev/page/about, it works. But, not via SSL. What is problem? Btw, my /etc/apache2/sites-available/website.conf code is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                          
        ServerName mydomain.com                                                              
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost                                                     
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website/                                                 

        <Directory /var/www/html/website>                                                   
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks                                                    
          AllowOverride All                                                                 
          Require all granted                                                               
        </Directory>                                                                        

        # LogLevel info ssl:warn                                                             

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log                                                
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined                                     
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log                                                
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined  

        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to                          
        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are                      
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to                          
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the              
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only                   
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".                             
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf 

</VirtualHost>
```

And, my .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine On                                                                      
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?load=page&page=$1 [NC]                 
ErrorDocument 404 /public/404.html
```

I'm developing it with in Windows using Laragon. And for Production env is: Ubuntu 16, PHP 7, and Apache2. Thanks.

Sorry for grammar mistakes, or you don't understand what I mean. Thank you very much was reading my question :)

Answer (score 3):

The line `<VirtualHost *:80>` tells apache that this configuration only applies for traffic coming on all interfaces (`*`) but only on the port 80 (`:80`). The `AllowOverride All` isn't applied on https (port 443) since it doesn't match.

To fix this, you need an other virtual host, `<VirtualHost *:443>`. You can either duplicate the content in the two virtual hosts or use an include, see this [server fault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/303744/serve-http-port-80-and-https-port-443-on-same-virtualhost#303750).

Comment: You mean, I need to make new virtual hosts with different port, to handle request via https, am I wrong? CMIIW. Thanks for response.

Comment: Right, you need two virtual hosts to handle http and https (the server fault question is exactly that). If you can access your server with https, you already have a `SSLEngine on` (and other `SSLCertificateFile`) somewhere, you may need to adapt/reuse it.